# Extracting Number and Select DB using the extracted Number

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

I have a PHP Class that is piping/reading email sent to a particular email id, and insert it to database table. This code work very fine. But now I wanted to extract the list of Number in the body of the mail that start with "1011" and use it to query the database. The body ($this->body) can have one or 10 number that start with 1011. Now I want to use "1011" to  SELECT from the database get the necessary information, and insert same to another Table. However This is NOT working. If I remove The SELECT query, I'm able to INSERT "1011" Directly to into my table. But I want to first Select this parameter before Inserting "1011".
PLS HELP ME!!!

```
    $matches = array();
    $pieces = explode(PHP_EOL, $this->body);
    $matches = preg_grep("/1011/", $pieces);
    //$results = implode(" | ",array_values($matches));
    //echo "Terminal IDs: ".$results." ";
    foreach ($matches as $columns)
    {
    $select = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_atm_data1 WHERE terminal_id = '$columns' ");
    $select = $select->fetchAll();
    if(count($select) > 0) {
    foreach($select AS $row) {
    $this->sol_id =$row['sol_id'];
    $this->timers =$row['timers'];
    $this->atm_name=$row['atm_name'];
    $this->terminal_id =$row['terminal_id'];

$insertFile = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO    tbl_request_dump1(terminal_id,sol_id,timers,atm_name) VALUES (:terminal_id,:sol_id,:timers,:atm_name)");
 $insertFile ->bindParam(':terminal_id', $columns);
 $insertFile ->bindParam(':sol_id', $this->sol_id);
 $insertFile ->bindParam(':timers', $this->timers);
 $insertFile ->bindParam(':atm_name',  $this->atm_name);

            $insertFile->execute();

}
}else {
            echo "No Terminal ID to Need to Save";
            die();
        }

}
```

Comment: This is simpler and much faster:  `INSERT INTO dump1 (...) SELECT ... FROM data1 WHERE ...`.  Only one `execute` to do, no fetching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my database table terminal_id is Integer datatype, so I converted the 
$column to Integer
IT WORK FINE!

```
  $term=(int)$columns;
   $select = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_atm_data1 WHERE terminal_id = '$term'");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use binding; otherwise, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: you can reduce the number of query called by using `where in` rather than going through countless for loop.